# "Open new window" option in Firefox from right-clicking Dock logo?

Tags: mac, firefox

EDIT: SITUATION RESOLVED, THANK YOU ALL!

*I've seen the related question for Windows, but I don't think it applies- feel free to let me know though if it does!*

**Background:**
I have a Macbook Air from 2015, in the OS X Yosemite version. I recently installed the Firefox browser, and am enjoying it very much.

In Safari, it's to right-click the Safari logo in the Dock and get a new window (see first image below). In Firefox, there does not seem to be an option (see second image below). Is there a way to manipulate it to do so?

**My research:** I've Googled the question but have only found solutions from Windows devices and am not sure how else to proceed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a mouse/Dock solution? I've used Macs for 30 years & never even thought to go to all that effort to just open a new window.. Cmd/N will do it without even moving the mouse. Cmd/T will open a new tab, right clicking on any link will give you other options, as will left-clicking with combos of Cmd &/or shift, depending on how you have your machine set. Diving right down to the Dock to do such simple things seems a lot of mouse-travel...

Comment: @Tetsujin 1 of 2: Not quite sure how to phrase this, but here we go- I have to be in the Firefox application for that to work. In the top-left corner of the screen next to the Apple logo it has to say Firefox, and not Finder, for example. If I do the commands when I'm "in" a different app, even if it's not open, they do something else.

Comment: @Tetsujin 2 of 2: so, in that case, there is no way (as far as I know) to make the computer think I am in the Firefox application if the one I've most recently used is something else except actually clicking on the Firefox logo, and then doing the command-N. And in that case, I have to open an old window of tabs, get a new window, and then "minus" the other, old window, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: then why don't you just bring the app you're trying to interact with to the front first? This feels like a solution to a problem which doesn't need to exist.

Comment: @Tetsujin: what do you mean by "bring to the front"?

Comment: "Make active"... the one showing at top left in the menu bar...  [The App] File Edit... etc. tbh, this is starting to feel like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86159/discussion-between--and-tetsujin).

Comment: It appears you're missing the "New Window" and "New Private Window," options which should be in a small section between the current windows and the "Options->" option. Running FF62.0.2 on macOS 10.13.6. Perhaps reinstalling Firefox might help?